# Mongoose not returning in insertMany() call

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Iam using mongoose with typescript in my project and for some weird reason the call is stuck at insertMany() statement and not returning though data gets inserted into mongodb.
With create() it works fine, but insertMany it just gets stuck.

```
public async saveUtrData(validatedXlJsonData: ICommissionUtrRow[], createdAt: Date, utrType: string) {
        try {
            logger.info("DB call :: utr collection");
            logger.info("transformation start");
            const utrArray: any = validatedXlJsonData.map((data) => {
                data.createdAt = createdAt;
                data.active = true;
                data.utrType = utrType;
                return data;
            });
            logger.info("transformation end");
            logger.info("insertMany start");
            **await commissionUtrModel.insertMany(utrArray);**
            logger.info("insertMany end");
            return Promise.resolve();
        } catch (exception) {
            if (utils.isEmpty(exception.stack)) {
                return Promise.reject(exception);
            } else {
                const error = responseFormatter.getErrorResponseWithBody(500, "CR001", msgC.SYSTEM_ERROR_OCCUR, exception.message);
                logger.error(error);
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help or suggestions for this problem.
We are using following version
"mongoose": "5.12.14",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"ts-node": "^8.10.2",

Comment: It depends on how big is your `utrArray` is. If it has a lots of records insertion may take time.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath - But the data is getting inserted into DB and even for smaller record its stuck there

Comment: are you using Atlas?

Comment: No plain monogodb on localhost

Comment: if localhost then some other issue. How about find or update, are those running fine? Can you also change the from `await` to `callback` one, just to check if it works.